# Content jumps in firefox - scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with which the content changes with JS.

The problem is on Firefox when parts of the content are really long scroll bars are added, making the width of the page change and this slightly moves the centered div holding my content in a bit.

The client does not like the jump. Is there a trick to get rid of this?

Comment: can you put up the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to force the scrollbar to be visible right from the start, even if not necessary. That way it wont jump.

```
<body style="overflow: scroll;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either force scrollbars using

`style="overflow: scroll;"`

or disable scrollbars using

`style="overflow: hidden;"`